# get ecs services for each ecs cluster using aws cli

Tags: bash, aws-cli

using bash script how do I get a list all the services in ecs for all the ecs clusters.

```
ecscluster=$(aws ecs list-clusters)

aws ecs list-services --cluster $ecscluster
```

Comment: `mapfile -t escluster < <(aws ecs list-clusters); aws ecs list-services --cluster "${escluster[@]}"`  maybe.

Comment: this does not see to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the other answer will work as list clusters will return a json not the cluster names only, here's a slightly modified version of the same command that will work:

```
all_services="$(for ecscluster in $(
aws ecs list-clusters --query 'clusterArns' --output text); do aws ecs list-services --cluster $ecscluster; done)"
 echo $all_services
```

It will return a json containing ARNs for services grouped by Cluster, and you can use something like jq to better process.

Answer (score 0):

This might achieve what you needed :

```
all_services="$(for ecscluster in $(
aws ecs list-clusters); do aws ecs list-services --cluster $ecscluster; done)"

echo "$all_services"
```